# Shebang line for ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: python

I'm writing a script to be run on ArcGIS for Desktop, which only runs on Windows machines.

Is there any use for a shebang line at its beginning, and if there is then what should it be (e.g. `#!C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\python.exe`)?

Comment: Do you have python 3 installed which includes the "shebang"  handler `py.exe`? If so read [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397). If not, your shebang will just be treated as a comment.

Comment: Arcmap 10.X  comes bundled with a (custom) Python 2 interpreter. And ArcPy is made to run with that version.

Answer (score 2):

Shebang is for Linux. On windows create a batch (.bat) file. e.g.

```
@echo off
python your_python_script.py parameters
```